# How to parse netstat command in order to get process name and PID from it?

Tags: linux, parsing, bash

I'm trying to determine what application is using certain port and get `netstat -tlnp | grep <port> for Linux`.

This command return the following output:

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)  
tcp  0  0 0.0.0.0:<port>  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  3591/java
```

I need to get in result only name of the process and PID, i.e java 3591.

What is best way to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try

```
ps -p $(lsof -ti tcp:80) o comm=,pid=
```

or

```
netstat -tlnp | awk '/:80 */ {split($NF,a,"/"); print a[2],a[1]}'
```

Comment: Thank you. Second part of the answer works and it's accepted.

Comment: Second one worked in Ubuntu 13.10 but I needed to `sudo`. I modified it a bit: `sudo netstat -tlnp | awk '/:80 */ {split($NF,a,"/"); print a[1]}' | xargs ps x -p`

Comment: This does not seem to work? `echo "tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1080/nginx: master" | awk '/:80 */ {split($NF,a,"/"); print a[2],a[1]}' ` returns `master`.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski: The output of `netstat` includes more than one space between columns for me, so adding a multispace delimiter to the AWK command seems to work: `netstat -tlnp | awk -F '  ' '/:80 */ {split($NF,a,"/"); print a[2],a[1]}'` (that's two spaces in the argument of `-F`)

Answer (score 15):

(Detracting slightly from your original question), to find out which process listens to a certain port number, I usually use the `lsof` command. For example:

```
lsof -i tcp:80
```

To show only the process name and PID, parse the output using:

```
lsof | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $1 " " $2}'
```

The `tail` command skips the output header while `awk` prints out the required columns.

#### Why `lsof`

Trying to `grep` the output of `netstat` can be messy as you'll need to make sure you're matching against the correct column. A robust solution can be rather long winded and difficult (for me anyway) to produce on-demand.

`lsof` saves you the trouble of matching the right ports, and has lots of other uses too, e.g. the inverse of what we're doing now (find out which ports are being used by a process), or determining which process is using a file / mount point (or the inverse). See [lsof manpage](http://www.netadmintools.com/html/lsof.man.html#lbAW) for more examples.

Answer (score 2):

awk + sed:

```
awk '{print $7}' | sed "s/\// /g"
```

Answer (score 1):

`... | awk '{print $7;}'| sed 's/\// /g'`

Answer (score 1):

Also you can get rid of that "you have to be root" message by redirecting stderr to /dev/null

```
netstat -tlnp 2>/dev/null | grep ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `netstat`, [is deprecated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/387406/209677) ([like `ifconfig`](https://serverfault.com/a/458639/407820) and others). Use [`ss`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ss.8.html) instead:

```
ss -tupln '( dport = :80 )' | grep -oP 'users:\(\(.*$'
```

Comment: Now if you add a port match on the local side to meet the questions criteria I might give you an upvote :)

Comment: Something like this?  `ss -tupln | awk '$5~/:80\>/{print gensub(/users:\(\("([^"]+).*/,"\\1",1,$NF)}'`

Comment: @tink To match a port you can [use  ss itself](https://www.howtogeek.com/681468/how-to-use-the-ss-command-on-linux/), for eg  `'( dport = :443 or sport = :https )'`

Answer (score 0):

```
netstat -tlnp 2>/dev/null | awk '/\.[0-9]:X/ {print $7}' | sed 's/\//\s/g'
```

where X in the awk bit is the port you're looking at.

Answer (score -1):

Try `netstat -p`

-p, --program Show the PID and name of the program to which each socket belongs.

Comment: -p <protocol> for os/x