# Simple "If - Then" case

Tags: bash

I need to create a specific workflow, namely:

- Check if certain TCP port is available
- If available - execute command A and then after, command B
- Otherwise - skip A, run B right away

Can you guys help me with that?

Note: Command A is nothing but a kill-switch for the app occupying the port

So for example I can start with something like:

```
lsof -wni tcp:20000 | grep listen
```

let's say that will return me something like

```
ruby    5055   ag    9u  IPv4 0x1f65a8e25318d67d      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:dnp (LISTEN)
```

Now how do I grab and pass that PID into `kill`? And how do I know if the first command yield no results (i.e. nothing is listening on 20000)?

Comment: I updated the answer to include getting the pid

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
nc -z localhost 3900 # 3900 -> your port
if [[ "$?" -eq "1" ]]; then
  do_a
fi
do_b
```

Edit: You changed your question - now if you want to actually get the PID that's another story... Try this (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247932/how-to-parse-netstat-command-in-order-to-get-process-name-and-pid-from-it)):

```
#change 80 to your port
pid=$(netstat -tlnp | awk '/:80 */ {split($NF,a,"/"); print a[2],a[1]}')

if [[ "$pid" -neq "0" ]]; then
  kill -9 "$pid"
fi
do_something
```

Comment: Thanks Chen - this seems to be a correct solution as well

Comment: Rather than checking the exit code separately, the first script could just be `if ! nc -z localhost 3900; then`.