# get the process name/id of the port number in netstat

Tags: java, unix, pid, netstat

I am using nestat command to check the port is free or not.

```
netstat -alp | grep <portnumber>
```

For a root user i am getting process name on which the port is used.
I have logged in as test user and am using netstat command to check the port.
But i am getting the output with warning that you are not a root user and process name is not displayed.
But i want to notify the person who is using the port number.
Is there any other command to display the process name/id for a non root user.

Comment: I think you may take a look at [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247932/how-to-parse-netstat-command-in-order-to-get-process-name-and-pid-from-it

Comment: Still i am not getting the process id/name. note that i am non root user.